# How to complie a static gdbserver

Tags: android, gdb, ld, gdbserver

I've make some changes to the source code of GDB, so I'd like to compile a new executable. I've successfully compiled a new GDB, but when it comes to compile gdb-server, it fails, I need to make `LDFLAGS = -static` in Makefile because Android does not have some library. The fail message is like this:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,--no-undefined -g -O2     -I. -I. -I./../common -I./../regformats -I./.. -I./../../include -I./../gnulib/import -Ibuild-gnulib-gdbserver/import -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-nonliteral -Wno-char-subscripts -Wempty-body  -DGDBSERVER \
-static  -Wl,--dynamic-list=./proc-service.list -o libinproctrace.so ax-ipa.o tracepoint-ipa.o format-ipa.o utils-ipa.o regcache-ipa.o remote-utils-ipa.o common-utils-ipa.o tdesc-ipa.o print-utils-ipa.o rsp-low-ipa.o amd64-linux-ipa.o linux-amd64-ipa.o -ldl -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libinproctrace.so] Error 1
```

It fails when using ld, so I want to know how to compile a static gdbserver?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message told you to do? That is, recompiling with the -fPIC flag.

Answer (score 0):

> `gcc -shared -fPIC ... -static ... -o libinproctrace.so ...`

In this command, you are asking GCC to link you a shared library `libinproctrace.so` with `-static` flag. GCC's answer: ["I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARJ8cAGm6JE).

So don't do that. Instead, edit the `Makefile` and add your `-static` specifically to the link line of `gdbserver`, rather than adding to *everything* on command line.